# Bigquery temporay function to return a struct

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I'm having a issue with my JS temporary function executed on Bigquery. This function returns an array of arrays in the JS code like the example below. What STRUCT am I supposed to use to save the each element of the array in a column of the table ?

What is returned by the function :

```
   var items = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]];
```

The STRUCT used :

```
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<lat FLOAT64, lon FLOAT64>>
```

The code is like that :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION

kMeans(x ARRAY<FLOAT64>,  
       y ARRAY<FLOAT64>, 
       iterations FLOAT64,  -- the number of iterations
       k FLOAT64)           -- the number of clusters

 RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<lat FLOAT64 , lon FLOAT64>>

LANGUAGE js AS """
'use strict'
function sumOfSquareDiffs(oneVector, anotherVector) {
  // the sum of squares error //
...
...
...
    return [[1.0, 2.0],[3.0, 4.0],[5.0, 6.0]];
}
""";

SELECT kMeans(lat, lon, 50.0, 3.0) FROM `dataset.table`
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI2iR.png)

Comment: Hi Amine just to make sure I understand the question: Are you using your function as part of an `INSERT` flow to a BigQuery table? Can you provide the full function code and the expected output for more clarity

Comment: I'm using a `SELECT` and I'm not getting `null` in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[[1.0, 2.0],[3.0, 4.0],[5.0, 6.0]]` is an array of arrays, rather than an array of structs. Here's a simple example that actually returns some output; hopefully this will help you to get started:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION

kMeans(x ARRAY<FLOAT64>,  
       y ARRAY<FLOAT64>, 
       iterations FLOAT64,  -- the number of iterations
       k FLOAT64)           -- the number of clusters

 RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<lat FLOAT64 , lon FLOAT64>>

LANGUAGE js AS """
'use strict'
function sumOfSquareDiffs(oneVector, anotherVector) {
  // the sum of squares error //
  return [{lat: 1.0, lon: 2.0},
          {lat: 3.0, lon: 4.0},
          {lat: 5.0, lon: 6.0}];
}

return sumOfSquareDiffs([1, 2], [3, 4]);
""";

SELECT kMeans([1.2], [3.4], 50.0, 3.0);
```